# How to find out the list of runtime libraries required by a process id or an executable in unix?

Tags: unix

I would like to know the command that gives out list of run time libraries required by a process PID or an executable in unix. Can someone help me here? I am using bash shell script in unix os environment.

Comment: `ldd $(which bash)`?

Comment: i have an executable called shibboleth-sp-2.6.0.tar.gz. so should it be ldd shibboleth-sp-2.6.0.tar.gz

Comment: You have an executable gzip-file? `man ldd`: _ldd - print shared object dependencies_

Comment: i have shibboleth-sp-2.6.0 folder in /opt folder. so it should be

Comment: i have shibboleth-sp-2.6.0 folder in /opt folder. so it should be

Comment: ldd /opt/shibboleth-sp-2.6.0

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: If there is such an executable, yes. Did you try it?